# In pandas dataframe - returning last value of cumulative sum that satisfies condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
index [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
part_1 [4, 5, 6, 4, 8, 4]
part_2 [11, 12, 10, 12, 14, 13]
new [6, 4, 8, 8, na, na]
```

I'm a beginner in python & pandas asking for support. In a simple dataframe, I want to create a new column that gives me the last row of a cumulative sum that satisfies the condition

```
df.part_1.cumsum() > df.part_2
```

So e.g. for the new column at index 0 I would get the value 6 as (4+5+6) > 11.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say `df.part_2`, You mean the cumulative sum of `part1` starting at that row?

Comment: Yes, starting at that row.

Comment: Could you add the expected output?

Comment: To clarify. For the first row of part_2 it should calculate the cumsum of part_1 that is >= first row of part_2. For the second row of part_2 it should calculate the cumsum of part_1 starting also at the second row. And the return should be the last row of the cumulative sum that satisfies the condition. Is that somewhat understanable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC here a `NumPy` based approach. The idea is to build an upper triangular matrix, with shifted versions of the input array in each row. By taking the cumulative sum of these, and comparing against the second column of the dataframe, we can find using `argmax` the first index where a value in the cumulative sequences is greater than the third dataframe column in the corresponding index:

```
a = df.to_numpy()
cs = np.triu(a[:,1]).cumsum(1)
ix = (cs >= a[:,2,None]).argmax(1)
# array([2, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7, 7, 0], dtype=int64)
df['first_ix'] = a[ix,1,None]
```

---

```
print(df)
   index  part_1  part_2  first_ix
0      0       4      11         6
1      1       5      12         4
2      2       6      10         4
3      3       4      12         8
4      4       8      14         6
5      5       4      13         8
6      6       6      11         8
7      7       8      10         4
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Just one thing. The last row of first_ix should be NA and not loop to the beginning. It is a time series and should not loop. Thanks! :)

Comment: There's no looping :) Sure, you can set it to np.nan by indexing directly on the result @Beginner23

Comment: I appreciate the support. Your answer works great! One last question. Additionally I would need the count of how many rows there are between the beginning row in 'part_1' and the result 'first_ix'. So for the first row of 'first_ix' it would be '3'. For the third result it would be '2'. Is there maybe a simple way to add this?

Comment: Yeh, would don't you give this one a try? :) `(cs >= a[:,2,None])` gives you a matrix of booleans, if you take the sum over the rows (or columns not sure) you get the count @Beginner23

Comment: I should have written bloody beginner as I started python only 2 months ago. :) But I´ll try. Will post answer.

Comment: Best way is to try yourself. Numpy is a pretty useful to look into, let me know if you get stuck @Beginner23

Comment: Oh, don't forget to accept the answer :) @Beginner23